# About return the largest int not larger than the base-2 logarithm of N. Could someone explain why these code below work?

Tags: java, logarithm

I don't understand why it works like this way, hope someone can help me with some detailed explanation, thank you so much

```
public class Ex14 {
public static int lg(int N) {
    int i, n;
    for (i = 0, n = 1; n <= N; i++) {
        n *= 2;
    }
    return i - 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(lg(1025));
}
```

}

Comment: And what don't you understand exactly?

Comment: @user2023608   x=log2N, which x is the answer we need to get, and which means N= 2*2*2......(x times), but why here uses n=n*2

Answer (score 0):

Each time round the loop, `n` gets multiplied by two. So the value of `n` goes 1, 2, 4, 8, 16... as the loop runs. That's generating the integer powers of two, right?